# XAML How apply styles according the value of paramter

Tags: c#, xaml

The goal is to check the state of parameters, the state of each parameter can take the enum value (lock, unlock, or valueIncorrect). The display
will be different according to the state of the parameter(e.g, lock rectangle will be red, unlock the text will be bold and vallueIncorrect will be gray).

In main class we have different parameters VarA, VarB and VarC for example. The state of each parameter can be different.

enum State{lock, unlock, valueIncorrect};

```
State VarA = lock
State VarB = unlock
State VarC = lock
```

before I was this style and a rectangle based on this style and When I pressed a button , the style will change, but the reaction will be the same on all parameter

```
<Style x:Key="DisplayLockGroup" TargetType="GroupBox">
 <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
     <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static local:LockMgt.Instance}, Path=isLocked}" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static local:LockMgt.Instance}, Path=isLocked}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style> 

<Rectangle x:Name="r_LockEcuTypes" Grid.Row="5" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column ="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Style="{DynamicResource DisplayLockRectangleGroup}" />
```

Now i would like to change this behavior, I have different parameter and I would like to individually check the state of this parameter and apply one style according to the value, but i don't know How I can do it.

E.g for one parameter:
`State VarA=lock => i` would like to apply the style1
`State VarB=unlock => i` would like to apply the style2
`State VarC=lock => i` would like to apply the style1 but if the value change from lock to unlock, I would like to apply the style2

I don't know how create the XAML to display correctly what is expected.

Comment: A function is executing code, I don't see how a function would have a state... objects/data can be stateful.

Comment: When you say function, do you mean a feature of your software or a C# function?

Comment: function mean a software function, it correspond to enum variable.

Comment: I suggest you change the wording of your question then. 'Function' is very misleading and makes it hard to understand the question.

Comment: Now if you also change your title and add some XAML and then explain how you want the visual presentation to change according to `State`, this will be a fine question.

Comment: You don't swap out the style of your current xaml element. Your options are basically, to change the properties via Style.Triggers (similar to your current approach), to have a Converter from State to some property values or to wrap your control and exchange inner styles via ControlTemplate.Triggers on the wrapper control. Maybe I can write an answer later, but not enough time now.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, depending on your actual needs, you have several options.

1. Converter from `State` to some property value
2. Change the properties via `Style.Triggers` (similar to your current approach)
3. Wrap your control and exchange inner styles via `ControlTemplate.Triggers` on the wrapper control

The following example is presenting three rectangles (`rect1`, `rect2` and `rect3` representing the approach with the same number) and a button that is responsible for changing the `State` of the ViewModel object in order to show how each rectangle reacts.

The XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- Used for 1. -->
        <local:StateToBorderBrushConverter x:Key="stateConverter"/>

        <!-- Used for 2. -->
        <Style x:Key="DisplayLockGroup" TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data1State}" Value="{x:Static local:State.locked}">
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data1State}" Value="{x:Static local:State.unlock}">
                    <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <!-- Used for 3. -->
        <Style x:Key="DefaultRectangleStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="LockedRectangleStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="UnlockedRectangleStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Green" />
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="grid1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="5" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="{Binding Data1State,Converter={StaticResource stateConverter}}" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="rect2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="5" Style="{StaticResource DisplayLockGroup}" />
        <ContentControl Margin="5" Grid.Row="2">
            <ContentControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Rectangle x:Name="rect3" Style="{StaticResource DefaultRectangleStyle}" />
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data1State}" Value="{x:Static local:State.locked}">
                            <Setter TargetName="rect3" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource LockedRectangleStyle}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data1State}" Value="{x:Static local:State.unlock}">
                            <Setter TargetName="rect3" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource UnlockedRectangleStyle}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Template>
        </ContentControl>
        <Button x:Name="ChangeStateButton" Grid.Row="3"  Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Change State" Click="ChangeStateButton_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Code

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public enum State
    {
        locked,
        unlock,
        valueIncorrect
    }

    public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyData : BaseViewModel
    {
        private State _Data1State;
        public State Data1State
        {
            get { return _Data1State; }
            set
            {
                if (_Data1State != value)
                {
                    _Data1State = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class StateToBorderBrushConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is State)
            {
                var s = (State)value;
                switch (s)
                {
                    case State.locked:
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                    case State.unlock:
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                    case State.valueIncorrect:
                        return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
            return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }


    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private MyData ContextData;

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ContextData = new MyData { Data1State = State.locked };
            grid1.DataContext = ContextData;
        }

        private void ChangeStateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (ContextData.Data1State)
            {
                case State.locked:
                    ContextData.Data1State = State.unlock;
                    break;
                case State.unlock:
                    ContextData.Data1State = State.valueIncorrect;
                    break;
                case State.valueIncorrect:
                    ContextData.Data1State = State.locked;
                    break;
                default:
                    ContextData.Data1State = State.locked;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pros and cons:

1. The converter approach is useful, if the same property type is targeted in many different control types. The converter is returning a Brush and it doesn't care whether that brush will be used in a `Rectangle.Stroke`, a `Border.BorderBrush` or some other context.
2. The style trigger approach is less flexible regarding the targeted control type, but it is easier to maintain changes of more than a single property based on the status.
3. The control template trigger approach is useful in some advanced scenarios. It allows separate definition of the styles for each state. However, I'd only recommend it if you actually derive your own custom control with additional functionality, not as an ad-hoc control template just for switching styles.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply an enum to color converter in the XAML binding

```
  Background="{Binding Source=StateValue, 
Converter={StaticResource stateValueColorConverter}}"
```

You'll easily find the detailed documentation: this is to give you the main idea of the usage.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to grek40, it is exactly what I want. I have try the option 3 and 2 and it works fine, I have use the case 2, it is most easily  to implement.
I have use the same behavior for add an image on lock and unlock state.

Comment: Please don't write comments / thanks as an answer. Instead, accept the answer that solved your problem. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score -1):

In the Xaml.cs file, How I can access to parameter rect3 on your proposal, when I try it I have compilation error "the name "rect3" does not exist in the current view, I have written

XAML.CS :

```
rect3.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

XAML :

```
<ContentControl Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="False">
                <ContentControl.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rect3" Style="{StaticResource DefaultRectangleStyle}" />
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data1State}" Value="{x:Static local:State.locked}">
                                <Setter TargetName="rect3" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource LockedRectangleStyle}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Data1State}" Value="{x:Static local:State.unlock}">
                                <Setter TargetName="rect3" Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource UnlockedRectangleStyle}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ContentControl.Template>
            </ContentControl>
```

Comment: Please, Stackoverflow is _not a forum_, where you discuss your programming progress in a single thread. Instead it is a question and answer platform, where each question should have a clear focus. If you have an issue regarding an answer, write a comment and ask for clarification. If you have a clarification that is in scope of your current question, edit the question, if you have a follow-up question that arises on using a solution, which is not directly related to the original question, ask a new separate question. __ONLY__ if you have an actual answer to the question, write an answer!